# creating a random blob in jdbc and writing it to oracle

Tags: sql, jdbc, blob, oracle11g

I want to create many blobs in java [in memory] and write it to Oracle table.

What I want is the blob[bits inside it] to be random or sudo random so that oracle would not be able to do a lot of pre-optimization while storing the blob to the table.

Something like

```
for(1..1000000)
{
blob = createRandomBlob(sizeOfBlob);
sqlText ="INSERT INTO test_blob (id, blob) VALUES(i, blob)";
stmt.executeUpdate(sqlText);
}
```

Can someone point what JAVA APIs I can use to create such blob[in memory rather than on disk] and write it to db ?

Thanks

Comment: The problem with this is that the Oracle driver has to support it.  I'm stuck with Oracle 10g drivers, and they don't even appear to support Java 6's Connection [`createBlob()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#createBlob%28%29).  I don't know if this was addressed in the 11g drivers.

Comment: I've just tested it with Oracle 10.2 + 11g drivers inside an EJB and it didn't work. It complained about connection.createBlob();

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick

```
  byte[] data = new byte[10000];
    fRandom.nextBytes(data);
    try
    {
      SerialBlob fSerialBlob = new SerialBlob(data);
    } catch (SerialException e)
    {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e)
    {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Dont know if there is a faster/efficient way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I can only answer for the "store it in the DB part", not sure about the "create a random blob array)

```
byte[] someBlob = createBlobBytes();
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO test_blob (id, blob) VALUES(?, ?)";
ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(someBlob);
stmt.setInt(1, id);
stmt.setBinaryStream(2, in, someBlob.length);
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

This should work fine with the 10.x drivers